# initialize a float32 matrix with random numbers in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, random, numpy, scipy

scipy.random.rand() and other functions in the same package
all produce arrays of float64 as output
(at least for python 2.7.3 64-bit on Mac OS, scipy version 0.12.0).

What I want is a rather large (N gigabytes) randomly initialized matrix of float32.
Is there an easy way to produce one directly, rather than allocating double space
for float64 then converting down to 32 bits?

Comment: The Python and SciPy versions are irrelevant. These functions come from NumPy and are only re-exported by SciPy.

Comment: FYI: For, uh, "historical reasons", scipy imports much of numpy into the `scipy` namespace.  `scipy.random` is actually `numpy.random`.

Comment: But no, there seems to be no way to get a `float32` directly, since there's no `dtype` argument on any of those functions. That's a shame.

Comment: You could preallocate the large float32 array, and then fill it in in batches.  That would still be reasonably fast, would would avoid having both the full float32 and float64 versions in memory at once.

Comment: Thank you all. I just wanted a confirmation that I'm not missing something obvious. Batch-population does makes sense as a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would preallocate the array, then copy in batches of random `float64`s as Warren Weckesser recommends in the comments.

If you're in for a hack, here's ten floats generated using uniform random bits:

```
>>> bytes_per_float = np.float32(0).nbytes  # ugly, I know
>>> np.frombuffer(random.bytes(10 * bytes_per_float), dtype=np.float32)
array([ -3.42894422e-23,  -3.33389699e-01,  -7.63695071e-26,
         7.02152836e-10,   3.45816648e-18,   2.80226597e-09,
        -9.34621269e-10,  -9.75820352e+08,   2.95705402e+20,
         2.57654391e+25], dtype=float32)
```

Of course, these don't follow any nice distribution, the array might contain NaN or Inf, and the code might actually crash on some non-x86 machines due to aligment problems.

Comment: IF you don't care what the distribution is, create a random array of half the length of `np.float64`, then `.view(np.float32)` it. But that's probably not much better than creating an `np.empty` array of the right size directly...

Comment: @Jaime: except that a very large `np.empty` might `mmap` the space (depending on the `malloc` implementation), and I know of at least one operating system that will give you an all-zero buffer in that case. Also, your solution provokes undefined behavior in the C code :)